# Is session changed when exception occur?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, session-cookies

I want to ask about behavior for next situation:

1. Request has come and routed to some action
2. Action handler changes session, do part of its job and encounter exception
3. The error page is rendered
4. The page is refreshed (<kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd>) to repeat the request.

So question:
Will repeated request be same as first request or `ROR` will serialize the session and set new `JWT` cookie on third step (so repeated request on forth step will be slightly different)?

Comment: Please provide **much** more context. It looks like you are using Ruby on Rails with JSON Web Tokens? How is your setup exactly?

Comment: @MoMolog: I do not know `ROR` at all. I just want to know how it behave in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails does not use JWT per default. It is possible to build Rails apps with JWT authentication with [third party gems](https://github.com/nsarno/knock).

Any changes made to the *standard rails session* before an exception occurred are perpetuated in the session and are available on the next request.

Pure JWT schemes - not using the standard rails session - are [stateless](https://www.jbspeakr.cc/purpose-jwt-stateless-authentication/) and do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Is this look OK that application state is changed when request fails?

Comment: Your application can make state changes to the session independently of the authentication status. 

However it will usually make sure that authentication related information such as "id of currently logged in user" inside the session only gets updated after the user has successful authenticated in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what kind of error do you have. When request ends with exception then session(cookies) not modified. But I'm pretty sure that you will not show exceptions to users in production, you'll display stylized error page. And that means you requests will end with success and change the session(cookies) in that case.

Comment: I thought that if exception occur and stylized error page is shown the framework do not change cookies by default. (do not setup `Set-Cookie` header) It seems reasonless because request is not finished

Comment: Technically it’s finished because you’ve handled exception. A request completed without error.

Comment: Actually it is handled by framework. It displays some default page for that.